# Transform sub query to joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

Transform following SQL query to Joins based query

```
SELECT * 
FROM STUDENTS 
WHERE StudentID IN (
  SELECT UserID FROM Stripe_Transactions where Quantity > 5
)
```

Since it is taking a long time to process!

Why does sub-query take long time?

Comment: Show output of `show create table STUDENTS` and `show create table Stripe_Transactions` and `explain SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE StudentID IN (SELECT UserID FROM Stripe_Transactions where Quantity > 5)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query

Comment: Changing to join form may not make any difference

Answer (score 0):

SELECT tb1.* from STUDENTS  tbl1
INNER JOIN Stripe_Transactions tbl2 on tbl1.StudentID=tbl2.UserID
where tbl2.Quantity > 5